# I need serious fix for lazy-load on images from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lazy-loading

All of the image sources are links to discord server images so i can't put them here.
I have tried every possible tutorial and github codes but i can't do it on my own.
I am stuck on this for a week now and i really need someone smarter to help me out!
I will use any code that works i have not tried jquery but i will if it will fix my problem!

HTML - lazyload.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Lazy Load</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.11.1/baguetteBox.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Zen+Dots&display=swap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <section class="gallery-block grid-gallery pt-4">
    
    <h2 class="text-center">Lazy Loading</h2>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row" id="image-builder"> </div>

    </div>
    
  </section>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/baguettebox.js/1.11.1/baguetteBox.min.js"></script>
  <script> baguetteBox.run('.grid-gallery', { animation: 'slideIn' }); </script>
  <script src="lazyload.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS - lazyload.js

```
var lazyload = [

];

(function () {


    function createDiv(imgSrc) {
  
      var NewDiv = document.createElement("div");
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      NewDiv.className = "col-6 item";
      NewDiv.appendChild(link);
      link.className = "lightbox lazy-load";
      img.className = "img-fluid scale-on-hover lazy-load p-1";
      img.loading = "lazy";

      link.appendChild(img);
  
      link.href = imgSrc;
  
      img.src = imgSrc;

      return NewDiv;
    }
  
    function createAndModifyDivs() {
      const newdiv = document.getElementById("image-builder");
      for (const imgSrc of lazyload) {
        newdiv.appendChild(createDiv(imgSrc));
      }
    }
  
    createAndModifyDivs();
    baguetteBox.run('#image-builder');
  
  }());
```

CSS - style.css

```
* {
  font-family: 'Zen Dots', cursive;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1063911992399765556/1064432310470053929/wallpaper.png?width=1920&height=1080');
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
  color: white;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  opacity: 90%;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}


.gallery-block.grid-gallery .item img {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.gallery-block.grid-gallery .item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {

  .gallery-block.grid-gallery .scale-on-hover:hover {
    transform: scale(1.02);
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) !important;
  }
}

.va {
  width: 95%;
  height: 75vh;
  object-fit: fill;
}

.vacategory {
  width: 90%;
  height: 65vh;
  object-fit: fill;
  border-radius: 5%;
  object-fit: fill;
}

img {
  border-radius: 3%;
}

.card {
  border: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

video {
  border-radius: 2%;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.icon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clear {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: snow;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.clear:hover {
  color: grey;
}

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: snow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: grey;
}

.baguetteBox-button {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

- I have tried "lazy-load" on the images and on the links. (Not working)
- I tried implementing [vanilla-lazyload:](https://github.com/verlok/vanilla-lazyload)  but i can't change IMG-src to DATA-src i don't know how to do that and there is very little information on this matter.
- I tried putting attributes "img.setAttribute ("data-src", imgSrc);" (Images disapear)
- I added img.widht="100px" img.height="100px" in js (Images disapear)
- I tried     img.style.width = "500px"; img.style.height = "500px"; (Images appear all at the same time)

I am creating website with more than 100 images per page (compressed but still they load slow and they load from bottom to top or just randomly) so PLEASE someone show me how to implement lazy-load here it is going to be the best thing in my life so thank you in advance!`

Comment: I tried your code with test images (1000+ image in lazy load) and it works fine, which google chrome version do you have?

Comment: I tried google chrome on phone newest version. i have tried on microsoft edge and if i stay at one place it loads even the last images i want to load them only when i am on view point. I can give you link to my website to check what is wrong but it is NSFW. When i stay at one place it loads even images that are way down on the page.

Comment: I modified your code, check this out [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qokafisofo/edit?html,css,js,output), as you can see it loads the images in lazy load (on my computer, and I disabled the cache in google chrome console)

Comment: Well if i use `https://placekitten.com/${i}/${i}` it works but if i put my own array from my js code "newdiv.appendChild(createDiv(lazyload));" it doesn't work how i can make it to work with my own array and not with link from the web?

Comment: Are you sure you put the img.width=500 / img.height = 500? (without "px") because that's important, otherwise the browser think that the image size is "1x1px" and load all the images at once

Comment: Yes just tested it with no px in the end, the images resize but the lazy-load doesn't work i am watching the scrollbar and i am not moving down on the page images still load. And again i am repeating myself i don't want to use (link with array on the web) i want to use (my own array (var lazyload = [];) from my js. Thank you for still trying to help i appreciate it.